# Си setenv глобально

Tags: c, environment-variables

Я полностью понимаю что,вопрос скорее риторический, и что `export ENV=value` это builtin команда шела.

Но все-же интересно спросить реально ли вывести env переменную за просторы программы и её наследников? Возможно есть какой нибудь хак как можно это сделать?

Возможно что ситуацию спасет некий плагин/драйвер для shell который сможет получать особую команду от программы?

И да, очень важную вещь забыл. Интересует именно временная замена, а не прописывание в ОС/пользовательские настройки. То-есть при закрытии шела, переменная должна пропадать.

Ps: Использую классический линуксовый c17.

**Добавлено спустя**

В Windows эту задачу решили способом инъекции. То есть в родителя производиться инъекция DLL, которая меняет environment по усмотрению запущенной программы.

Раз уж сложный вопрос, то может будем плясать от схожих манипуляций?

Во многих статьях ещё ссылаються на gdb

```
$ sudo gdb -p PROCESSID
(gdb) call putenv("MYVAR=myvalue")
(gdb) detach
```

Comment: А чем плох стандартный способ через eval?

Comment: Он как раз сейчас и используется. По сути это хоть и рабочий, но костыль.. Хочется убрать костыль в недра программы и сделать все проще

Comment: Я так полагаю что у того-же bash и им подобным все-же есть какой-то апи который позволяет это сделать без применения жестких костылей.

Comment: Костыль - это использование переменных окружения. И глобально их изменить нельзя, так как они дублируются в каждом запущенном процессе.

Comment: @user7860670 Я прекрасно осознаю как работает env, просто ищу возможные варианты повлиять на env своего родителя так, что-бы он уже передал переменную остальным запущенным от его имени программам. И да, я поэтому и написал что вопрос скорее всего риторически, не имеющий решения кроме как через eval запускать программу. Но у этого способа есть несколько недостатков. Один из которых - это профукать secrets если код запустят без eval

Comment: @EugeneX, а как ты запускаешь порожденные процессы? Там же по-любому есть способ передать переменные окружения.

Comment: А что такое "линуксовый c17", для других ОС стандарт другой?

Comment: Вот здесь можно взять переменную целевого процесса `/proc/<PID>/environ` и задать её с помощью `setenv` для текущего.

Comment: @megorit ну студия от мелкософта досихпор в стандарте C11 работает, и клали больт они на Си разработчиков, а в линуксе народ разбилс на пару лагерей. Кто-то в C17 пишет, кто-то в C11, большинство на с2х

Comment: @megorit Нельзя через environ, во первых он readonly, во вторых он отображает только изначальное состояние при запуски процесса. То-есть процесс запустился с файла environ поместил переменные оккужения в `extern char **environ;` и после ему вообще пофигу что там в файле происходит, и происходящие изменения в процессе тоже не отображают состояния.

Comment: Так а наффига вам `IPC` через переменные окружения? Это какая-то дичь. Есть более адекватные способы.

Comment: Можно попробовать через ptrace, так как это делает gdb, когда аттатчиться к другому процессу. Надо будет вызвать malloc, скопировать туде текущий environtment, добавить (или изменить) переменную, занести в environ адрес памяти из malloc и отпустить процесс работать дальше. Можете поиграться (сорсы gdb существуют, manpages ptrace тоже, в общем, ваяйте)

Comment: @megorit было-бы классно, не использовать env вовсе, но к сожалению не тот случай :(

Comment: @avp спасибо! Рассмотрю ваш вариант.